# Bayes model comparison

Tags: bayesian, model-selection

I have two Bayes models, and let's say that model A is more complex than model B. I know a priori that model A is a good model for the data. I want to make the claim that model B is applicable as well. One idea that comes to mind is the use of WAIC. Is there any acceptable score classification that says that if the WAIC difference is below some level, the models are considered close? For example, we can say that models with the Bayes factor below three are similar. Does it make sense to compare distance (like L2) between distributions of observables (marginalized over parameters of each model space)?

Comment: The Bayes factor is the standard solution for model comparison.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you! In my case, the simple addition of Bernoulli random variables to compute the Bayes factor( as it is suggested in pymc3 guide) results in poor sampling. Therefore, I would like to consider other options.